# How to prevent toggle action if something has focus with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, toggle, jsfiddle

See here:
http://jsfiddle.net/kbkPL/

Right now on mouseenter and mouseleave the hidden slide panel slides in and out.

If the user has focus on that input box I want to keep the panel open (and prevent it from sliding back out) until focus is lost or the user has pressed submit.  How would I accomplish this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a possibility:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#promoContentTrigger").mouseenter(function(){
    $("#promoContentPanel").toggle("fast");
    $(this).toggleClass("hideTrigger");
});
$("#promoContentPanel").mouseleave(function(){
    if ($(".textBox").is(":focus")) {return;}
    $("#promoContentPanel").toggle("fast");
    $("#promoContentTrigger").removeClass("hideTrigger");
});
```

});​